# SQL Server - Order Table Data Before Updating

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, sql-update, sql-order-by

I need to add a number value to each record in a SQL table. I want to add this number after sorting the data, so that the number (which will be used for ticket entry) will appear in numerical order when viewed by endusers.

I want to sort the table data by [AssignedLocator] and then by [PartNo], before assigning a numerical value in the [TicketNumber] column. I've tried a few different ways, but without success. I most recently tried using a subquery:

```
DECLARE @TicketNumber INT
SET @TicketNumber = 100000;

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [AssignedLocator],[PartNo]) AS RowNum
    FROM [Staging].[dbo].[PI_6F_Forms]
)
UPDATE CTE
SET [TicketNumber] = @TicketNumber,
    @TicketNumber = @TicketNumber + 1;
```

This still incremented the value in the [TicketNumber] field based on the ID num of the table

Comment: Your issue is [not reproducible](https://dbfiddle.uk/w6Opho0v). Your current query is working. Unless your description is misleading, in that case you need to add sample data and expected output to your post.

Comment: You're using something called quirky update, but without any real guarantees it will respect your sort or work properly, better use a subquery or cte as the answers below demonstrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to update Ticket Number incrementally using `row_number()` :

```
DECLARE @TicketNumber INT;
SET @TicketNumber = 100000;

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT *, @TicketNumber + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [AssignedLocator], [PartNo]) AS RowNum
    FROM mytable
)
UPDATE CTE
SET [TicketNumber] = CTE.RowNum
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/KUcGZfCP)